# Deploying Images from gitlab in a new namespace in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I have integrated gitlab with Kubernetes cluster which is hosted on AWS. Currently it builds the code from gitlab to the default namespace. I have created two namespaces in kubernetes one for production and one for development. What are the steps if I want that to be deployed in a dev or a production namespace. Do I need to make changes at the gitlab level or on the kubernetes level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done at the kubernetes level. Whether you're using `helm` or `kubectl`, you can specify the desired namespace in the command.

As in:

- `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml --namespace <desired-namespace>`
- `helm install stable/gitlab-ce --namespace <desired-namespace>`

Alternatively, you can just change your current namespace to the desired namespace and install as you did before. By default, helm charts or kuberenetes yaml files will install into your current namespace unless specified otherwise.